# Error en el programa, no da una respuesta correcta

Tags: c++, dev-c++

El problema es que es como si no detectara la variable `n3`.

Por ejemplo, pongo 7 en `n3`, 6 en `n1` y 5 en `n2`, me sale que la mas alta es `n1` cuando lo es `n3`, y si pongo por ejemplo 6 en `n2`, 7 en `n3` y 5 en `n1`, me sale que la mas alta es `n2`, lo cual tampoco es cierto.

Espero respuesta, gracias ;D.

Este es el código:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n1,n2,n3;

    cout<<"\nIngrese 3 numeros, por favor: "; cin>>n1>>n2>>n3;

    if (n1>n2 and n3){
    cout<<"\nEl mayor es: "<<n1;

    }
    else {

    if(n2> n1 and n3){
        cout<<"\nEl mayor es: "<<n2;
    }
        else {
            cout<<"\nEl mayor es: "<<n3;
        }
}

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema está en las expresiones lógicas que usas para comparar el contenido de las variables.

Dices, por ejemplo

`if (n1>n2 and n3){`

Supongo que quieres ver si n1 es mayor que n2 Y mayor que n3. Pues bien, lo que REALMENTE estás diciendo ahí es que

`si (n1 mayor que n2 AND n3)`

Pero ese **AND** es una expresión lógica y estás evaluando n3 como un booleano. Tu condición será cierta si, de forma simultánea, n1>n2 **Y** n3 es evaluado como `true`.

Para hacer la comparación que buscas, debes comparar de forma explícita la relación entre las variables

`if (n1>n2 and n1>n3){`

Comment: Oh, muchas gracias! Supongo que todavia me tengo que familiarizar con detallar cada pequeña cosa jajaj. Suerte ;D

Comment: @Drakzorg con gusto! Recuerda marcar la repuesta como aceptada si con esto se resuelve completamente tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

El [comparador lógico Y (*and*)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puerta_l%C3%B3gica#Puerta_AND) en C++ se expresa habitualmente como doble [et](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%26) `&&` no como `and`, siendo `&&` la forma principal y `and` la forma alternativa tal y como recoge el [estándar C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf) (traducción mía):

> #### 5.5 Símbolos alternativos.
>
> 1. Se proveen símbolos alternativos para algunos operadores y puntuaciones.
> 2. En todos los aspectos del lenguaje, cada símbolo alternativo se comporta igual que su símbolo principal, excepto por su escritura. Los símbolos alternativos se define en la siguiente tabla:
>
>    ```
>    | Alternativo Primario | Alternativo Primario | Alternativo Primario |
>    |    <%         {      |   and        &&      |   and_eq      &=     |
>    |    %>         }      |  bitor       |       |   or_eq       |=     |
>    |    <:         [      |   or         ||      |   xor_eq      ^=     |
>    |    :>         ]      |  xor         ^       |    not        !      |
>    |    %:         #      |  compl       ~       |   not_eq      !=     |
>    |    %:%:       ##     |  bitand      &       |                      |
>    ```

Los símbolos alternativos son una opción para sistemas en que algunos símbolos no están disponibles, deberías usar la forma principal si ésta está disponible.

El comportamiento de los operadores relacionales está descrito en §7.6.9 (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 7.6.9 Operadores relacionales.
>
> 1. Los operadores relacionales se agrupan de izquierda a derecha. [*Ejemplo*: `a<b<c` significa `(a<b)<c` no `(a<b)&&(b<c)`. —*fin del ejemplo*]. […].
> 2. Los operandos convertidos **deben tener tipo aritmético**, enumeración o puntero. Los operadores `<`, `>`, `<=` y `>=` devuelven verdadero o falso. **El tipo del resultado es booleano**.

El comportamiento del comparador lógico está descrito en §7.6.14 (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 7.6.14 Operador Y lógico.
>
> 1. El operador `&&` agrupa de izquierda a derecha. **Los operandos se convierten contextualmente a booleano**. El resultado es verdadero si ambos operandos son verdaderos y falso en caso contrario. Al contrario que `&`, `&&` garantiza **evaluación de izquierda a derecha**: el segundo operando no se evalúa si el primero es falso.
> 2. **El resultado es de tipo booleano**. Si la segunda expresión se evalúa, la primera expresión se secuencia antes que la segunda.

---

Sabiendo todo esto, analicemos tu expresión `n1>n2 and n3`. Sabemos que ambos operadores se evalúan de izquierda a derecha y que ambos devuelven un valor booleano, así que sea cual sea el orden de evaluación (`(n1>n2) and n3` o `n1>(n2 and n3)`) acabarás comparando un valor booleano contra un entero (`int`).

Los enteros son implícitamente convertibles a booleano siendo cero `false` y cualquier otro valor `true`. Los booleanos son implícitamente convertibles a entero siendo `false` cero y `true` uno.

Por lo tanto: "*7 en `n3`, 6 en `n1` y 5 en `n2`*" genera la siguiente expresión:

```
6>5 and 7
```

Que se evalúa como:

```
true and 7
```

Siete es diferente de cero, por lo que también es `true`:

```
true and true
```

Verdadero y verdadero es definitivamente verdadero.

#### Propuesta.

[Usa `std::max`](https://tio.run/##RY3PCsIwDMbvfYqglw0muA0vruzmwXfwUro4C2ta@keUsWefGSiGfIf8ki@f9v4war2ue0N6ygOCNC6mgMr24s/UNLpg0oOhyNHQCKQsRq80QkxDJ4ShBFYZKspZANc2U11RU1HL6w1pl5OUuxtdaQwYEVqgbDG4WIF3Ae7q6cIZdh1oQ31PNathsf9nBymBH1wmznqzBSPfb9CqVzFzHnAgULuU38yAKQeCYyeWdT3VouYWHw):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n1,n2,n3;

    cout<<"\nIngrese 3 numeros, por favor: "; cin>>n1>>n2>>n3;
    cout << "\nEl mayor es: " << max({n1, n2, n3});

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! Ya había resuelto el problema, pero me diste una solución más rápida y que implica menos trabajo,supongo que la terminré usando ya que la veo útil, en cuanto a las expresiones, uso las escritas en letras, por ej "and", ya que me parece más sencillo de tal manera, además me confundo menos y no me sé los códigos para los demás símbolos. Suerte ;D